# find a number in a certain environment in a file and modify it

Tags: python, file, numbers

I have a large file which contains many occurences of certain syntax: `(width 0.15)`.

The number `0.15` can be any floating point number. I wish to find all instances of these numbers and modify them. I know how to modify them using `float('0.15')+modifier` and also I know how to make a string of the result again.

I have trouble finding the numbers. I looked at the `re` module but don't quite know how to match the numbers themselves and not include the environment with the match.

So I know how to match all the occurrences of the entire environment `(width 0.15)` using `re`. I know how to modify the number string. But I don't know how to match for the actual number within the environment. How to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could use lookarounds:

```
s = '(width 0.15)'

match = re.search('(?<=\(width )\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?=\))', s)
```

output:

```
match.group()
# '0.15'
```

For all occurrences + conversion to float:

```
out = list(map(float, re.findall('(?<=\(width )\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?=\))', )s))
```

output:

```
[0.15]
```

regex:

```
(?<=\(width )  # match should be preceded by "(width "
\d+            # one or more digits
(?:\.\d*)?     # optionally, a dot with zero or more digits
(?=\))         # match should be followed by ")"
```